Java Optional vs Scala Option as a method parameter
From my experience in Java world it's a common to avoid an Optional as a parameter of a function but rather use it as a return type (related SO question)
I recently started getting familiar with Scala and saw many usages of Option as a method parameter type, for example
def myTestFunction(x: Option[Int]): Int. The Java variant would be int myTestFunction(Optional<Integer> x)
I don't see how Scala variant lucks all the issues possible in Java variant (for example passing null as an Option/Optional value).
Is my understanding correct that it's just a matter of taste to use or not to use Option/Optional as a method parameter understanding the possible drawbacks?

Seems like different philosophies. In Java, null is treated as a legitimate way of representing "no value", even if many modern APIs try to avoid it. I don't know Scala, but from the couple things I've read just now, null seems to only exist for interoperability with Java. If not interacting with Java, then null should be avoided at all costs.

We never use null in Scala if not for interop with Java. With Scala 3, there's even "explicit null" flag to be safer. That's why Scala's Option is just fine as a parameter.

I'd say that null is fine - for optimization inside a library's internals. But it's avoided in public API as it's error prone. In Scala it's more "make it correct, then optimize" philosophy while Java`s recommendations are more like "avoid the death by a thousand cuts".

As a Java coder I have never ever seen an example where Optional as a parameter type had any net advantages over allowing null. I read that an alternative to a nullable parameter is an overloaded version of the method that hasn‘t got the parameter at all. IMO it sometimes helps, sometimes not. I too have heard Scala programmers say that they use Option a lot more. I canbt tell whether there is a rationale for that.

Mostly personal preference of your coding style. The initial idea of that Java should not use Optional came from Java architect Brian, so many people follow his lead, but there is no inherent issues with using optional other than the historical null baggage. Scala is entirely different language even though it runs on JVM, and uses different philosophy so don't use Java mentality with Scala

Java devs don't see Optional as a modeling tool. Only as a helper. That is the main difference.

Optional doesn't freely adjust itself which means you can't compose your code. Scala has implicits and use-site generics co/contravariance configuration (2 things java does not have) which presumably provides some room to sensibly stick Option(al) into parameter types in scala where it's not such a good in idea in java.
Imagine you have a method that takes in a list of numbers and, I dunno, calculates the average of them all as doubles. Here it is:
double avg(List<Number> ns) {
  double v = 0.0;
  for (Number n : ns) v += n.doubleValue();
  return v / ns.size();
}
// There's plenty to improve here. The point isn't
// an esoteric deep-dive on how to average numbers
// as accurately as possible. It's just an example.

You have a list of integers, and, hey, those are numbers, so, you call the method:
List<Integer> myNums = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4);
System.out.println(avg(myNums));
// Expecting to see: 2.5

Except you don't see that. It doesn't even compile. The compiler complains that you need a List<Number>, and a List<Integer> evidently doesn't count. The compiler is correct, because the method could execute ns.add(5.5) which would stick a double in your list of integers and that's wrong. It doesn't, but that's not how it works: A signature (double avg(List<Number> ns) defines what a method can do. The compiler ensures all makes sense for all possible things the method is legally allowed to do. What it actually does is immaterial. It could do the add thing therefore, you can't call it.
Let's fix that!
double avg(List<? extends Number> ns) {
... everything the same ...
}

and now all is great. What happened under the hood is that we told the compiler to actively prevent any attempt to invoke ns.add(5.5), and, indeed, if you tried that, the compiler would complain that you can't call .add on a List<? extends Number>. At all. The only thing you can call it with is literally null because that expression is every reference type at once. Which is academic; ns.add(null) is kinda useless.
That's the kind of thing that Optional doesn't do so well.
Same principle, slightly different story:
I have a method that searches for the first element that 'fits' a given regexp. If it is found, this element is duplicated and added to the end of the list. nulls are considered to match null for some reason. If no such element is found, nothing happens:
void dupeFirstMatch(List<String> ts, Pattern regex) {
  for (String t : ts) {
    if (regex.matcher(t).matches()) {
      ts.add(t);
      return;
    }
  }
}

Now let's attempt to mix optionality in this, the same way we injected ? extends to 'make it work' for any type of number, we now want to inject something to fix the following problem with the above code: This method works regardless of optionality. If we attempt to execute this operation on a list of Optional<String>> instead we get stuck! However, the nature of this operation means we should be able to do it: The operation makes just as much sense on 'optional strings' as it does on 'definitely existing strings'. After all, we only add an element we got from the list in the first place, so it cannot possibly be 'no value' unless the input allows no-value.
In other words, if we have a method that:

Is willing to check if any input value is optional.NONE / null.
Ensures that any output it generates (writing to a list is output, returning something is output, etc) is definitely never NONE/null...

Then the optionality does not matter. Either one is fine.
But you cannot express that with Optional. There is no way to have what ? extends and friends do.
This results in Optional<T> being fundmentally problematic. Even if you have code that can deal with the notion that it might be wrapping a NONE, you can't express that. Thus, you're forced to unroll everything even if you don't want to and the business logic doesn't require it.
Because of that, just unroll your optionals ASAP, and having methods that take optional as parameter type are antithetical to that rule, hence, you shouldn't have them.
That explains why the java community doesn't like it, and should give you some handholds to go hunt for scala-specific features that obviate this problem (or, the scala community as large doesn't mind any of this; I don't know).

That is a lot words and I don't have any idea of what are you trying to say (just like when I read Java code lol). Okay, bad jokes aside, can't you just use List<Optional<String>> for that weird method of yours?

"Too long, did not understand" is not a useful comment, @Luis. Then spend some more time reading it, or move on by, it wasn't meant for you. a List<Optional<String>> would not work. After all, I cannot pass a List<String> to such a method.

Well it is useful in the sense that it is true. I would love to be more specific but I don't know what exactly to say other than that. It is too long and I don't understand what is the point you are trying to make. - Anyways, I did try to understand it, I actually re-read it multiple times and the best I could come with was asking why passing a List<Optional<String>>. Yo your answer to that, sure that is exactly the same thing would happen in Scala, a String is a not a Option[String]. Making that subtyping relationship work tho is a interesting discussion, that is the case in TS

While allowing T <: Option[T] could be good to reduce some noise / boilerplate. It has nothing to do with allowing its use in parameters. This boils down to what I mentioned in the other comment. In Java you don't see Optional as a modeling tool.
